# htaccess Canonicalization for https url (http://www)

Tags: .htaccess, url, canonicalization

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www.website.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I used this to redirect:

- http to https
- http://www to https://www
  both these work fine now. Yet I'm not able to redirect https://website.com to https://www.website.com

  `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
  RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]`

I tried this code changing http to https, but still it does not work. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www.website.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

With `[OR]`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This code worked for me. Thank you!